# Laravel can't change config value

Tags: laravel, configuration, environment-variables, laravel-5.6

I found the problem, i'll try to use a homestead or docker.

> if i restart `php artisan serve` the changed values are applied.

Same my post: [Laravel can't change config value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570831/laravel-cant-change-config-value)

---

I make route

```
Route::get('/config', function () {
    return dd(config('app'));
});
```

And cant change my config/app.php, for example i want to change

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'test'),
'client_url' => env('APP_CLIENT_URL', 'test'),
```

I set

```
APP_CLIENT_URL=str1
APP_URL=str2
```

and there is something inexplicable:

My `"url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"` !!! not default 'test' or from .env, I did not set such a value.
My client_url contains the old value, after I cached the config.

This is not production, i accidentally run config:cache, but after i remove all cache from **bootsrap/cache**, **storage/framework/cache** and running `cache:clear`, `config:clear`.

After running `config:cache` values from the .env were put in config, but I do not want to constantly change cache in development and it is not recommended in the documentation.

How can I easily change .env in in developing?

Comment: try this command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I wrote above that I already tried, it's strange that it does not help

Comment: And what cache driver you are using?

Comment: file, in config/cache.php all default

Comment: Don't use cache in dev... And all your changes in .env will work straight away...

Comment: I already understood this, I did it by accident, and now apparently there are no ways to delete this cache?

Comment: php artisan config:clear should clear it, isn't it?

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help. You can check my problem: 1) git clone https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-nuxt.git 2) cd 3) composer install 4) php artisan serve 5) open http://localhost:8000/config 6) try changing not using config:cache. config:clear does not work for me

Comment: Maybe you just get a HTTP cache? Hard refresh browser? :D Did you tried with other dev environment like docker or homestead instead of `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @VaidasLungis Hard refresh the browser does not help), I want to try docker or homestead, need to find time